# How to fix cell reusability issue using MVVM pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to implement MVVM pattern without 3-d party libraries for data binding.

I have a `UICollectionView` with a `StoriesViewModel`.
`StoriesViewModel` is a class which holds an array of models.

To each cell I assign a respective `ViewModel` which I create in a `cellForItemAt` method, like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.storiesCollectionViewCell, for: indexPath) as! StoriesCollectionViewCell
        
    let story = viewModel.getStory(for: indexPath)
    let storiesCellViewModel = StoriesCellViewModel(story: story)
        
    cell.viewModel = storiesCellViewModel
    cell.setup()
        
    return cell
}
```

Cells are `dequeueReusable` and images are being reused, which I can't fix with simple line `imageView.image = nil` at the start of `cellForItemAt` method, which worked for me previously when I used MVC. I guess it's something with assigning viewModels to cells.

Cell code (without views and constraints):

```
class StoriesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    //
    var viewModel: StoriesCellViewModel?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        //
        setupViews()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        //
    }
    
    func setup() {
        storyImageView.image = nil
        viewModel?.fetchImageData(completion: { (imageData) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.storyImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        })
        titleLabel.text = viewModel?.title
        authorLabel.text = viewModel?.author
        brandNameLabel.text = viewModel?.brandName
    }
    
}
```

I also tried `viewModel = nil` in `prepareForReuse` method, and it didn't work. Is that a common problem in approaching MVVM pattern and what is the way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show the code for your cell - What code do you execute in response to assigning a view model to `cell.viewModel` - That assignment should trigger the code to update the cell's views from the view model.

Comment: @Paulw11 Edited the post. I call a cell setup() method after an assignment.

Comment: You should call `setup()` in a `didSet` for `viewModel`

Comment: @Paulw11 Changed it, same result.

Comment: The problem probably exists in code you haven't shown.  For example, do you actually add subviews in `setupViews`?  Do you make sure that `setupViews` is only called once?  Have you set a breakpoint in `setup` to confirm that it is being called when the cell is re-used?

Comment: @Paulw11 First two yes. About the last one I am not sure how to do it, I'll check it. And if it's not being called after reusing, what's the fix?

Comment: The code you have shown is calling `setup`, so it should be being called, but use the debugger to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is going on is that by the time the image is loaded to be displayed in your cell, the cell itself might have already been dequeued to be reused for another row of the collection view.

This is a common issue that can occur when you're using reusable cells.

One way to solve this might be to add a check when the image data is finally loaded, to make sure you're still dealing with the same cell as before (i.e.: still configured with the same view model that initiated the image load).

Maybe you can use an unique identifier for each view model to do this:

```
viewModel?.fetchImageData(completion: { (imageData) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Check here if it still makes sense to attribute this image to this cell
        self.storyImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
})
```

Comment: How can I do this check?

Comment: I only see it if I pass an identifier as a parameter in a setup() and move it back to cellForItemAt. Is this the right approach? I was told that "You should call setup() in a didSet for viewModel"

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't store specific image in a non-specific cell, i.e.; a reusable cell.

Because by the time your async fetch returns, that cell may already be reused to display another image.

The usual approach is to create a separate cache, which is updated by async fetch, followed by a table view reload in which `indexPath.row` is used as array index to access the cache.

This is pretty straight-forward in Apple MVC.

So the problem now is how to implement it in MVVM.

I'd say there's no benefit to using view model for reusable cells. You are just making things difficult for yourself.

But no one dares to challenge MVVM these days, it seems. Devs always blame themselves for not fully grasping the power of MVVM. No, challenge it. MVVM does not magically solve everything.

That being said, I'll attempt answering your question.

`self.storyImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)`

You store a specific image in a non-specific reusable (variable) cell.

If you call fetch in cell view model, then it needs a callback to pass that image to view controller which then triggers a table view reload. You should avoid capturing cell references and make run-time condition checks. The safest bet is to prepare data and trigger SDK to do the rest.

In fact, I would argue that view model is about updating view whenever model changes. But this requires proper binding, which is lacking in UIKit. So all these efforts are just so that you can do networking which produces side effects in callback and indirectly trigger a view update.

You may verify this by not calling fetch in cell view model. Then your view model becomes useless. MVVM becomes MVC with extra steps. There's no point passing a view model to setup cell properties when those properties are public and meant to be setup in `cellForRow:` by SDK design.